# How to Update a Single record despite multiple Occurances of the same ID Number?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that looks like the below table:

[image]

Every time the user loan a book a new record is inserted.

The data in this table is derived or taken from another table which has no dates.

I need to update this tables based on the records in the other table: Meaning I only need to update this table based on what changes.

Example: Lets say the user return the book *Starship Troopers* and the book return is indicated to ***Yes***.
How do I update just that column?

***What I have tried:***

I tried using the MERGE Statement but it works only with unique rows of data, meaning you get an error if the same ID appears more than once.

I also tried using a basic UPDATE Statement and a JOIN but that's not going well.

I am asking because I have ran out of ideas.

Thanks for reading

Comment: *...I need to update this tables based on the records in the other table...* In order to help you you have to show us this **other** table's schema and sample data

Comment: Its the same as the one above: But gets a Bulk Insert Daily which I do not control. So I am simply trying to grab the new data out of it as it continuously appends to hold old and new, really bad design. Same structure as above.

Comment: can't you add an identity column in your Table so that there is a least you can identify the latest entry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to update `BooksReturn` in target table based on the same column in source table

```
UPDATE t
   SET t.booksreturn = s.booksreturn
  FROM target t JOIN source s
    ON t.userid = s.userid 
   AND t.booksloaned = s.booksloaned
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4e59/1)** demo

Comment: This looks like it is going to work, let me play around with this:

Comment: This does not work when their are multiple UserIDs. Like Multiple users. Same problem I was having. If there are more than one user and more than one sets of repeated IDs, the update does not work. I have updated the fiddle.

Comment: Please post a link to updated sqlfiddle. When you change it you need to hit `Build Schema` and copy address in your browser.

Comment: Thanks my friend, this was a strange one but I am glad for you help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simple Update & Insert statement.....
Two table A & B
From B you want to insert data into A if not exists other wise Update that data....
,First Insert into temp table....

```
SELECT * 
INTO   #MYTEMP 
FROM   B 
WHERE  BOOKSLOANED NOT IN (SELECT BOOKSLOANED 
                           FROM   A)
```

,Second Check data and insert into A.

```
INSERT INTO A 
SELECT * 
FROM   #MYTEMP
```

And at last write one simple update statement which update all data of A. If any change then it also reflect to that data otherwise data as it is.

You can also update from #MYTEMP table.

Comment: I am using the MERGE STATEMENT to INSERT, which works perfectly. How ever it's just hard to update. Thanks for the ideas.